# Modify HTML listbox value using VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

How do i set the value of a listbox to some already existing value, say `text3`, using VBScript in an HTML page.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <select name="sometext"  id="dsds">
        <option value="1">text1</option>
        <option value="2">text2</option>
        <option value="3">text3</option>
        <option value="4">text4</option>
        <option value="5">text5</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my VBScript code:

```
Dim ie
Set ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate("hey12.html")
ie.width = 900
ie.height = 600
ie.Visible = 1
WScript.sleep(5000)
Set Helem1 = IE.document.getElementByID("dsds")
Helem1.value = "text3"
```

Using the above code, I am not able to modify the listbox value or text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by index using the `SelectedIndex` property of the `<select>` element. This is zero-based. Since `text3` is the third option, use a value of `2`:

```
Set Helem1 = IE.document.getElementByID("dsds")
Helem1.SelectedIndex = 2
```

Or you can check the text value of each `<option>` element and, when you find the one you're looking for, set its `Selected` property to `True`:

```
Set Helem1 = IE.document.getElementByID("dsds")

For Each o In Helem1.Options
    If o.InnerText = "text3" Then o.Selected = True
Next
```

Comment: Thanks .. It works. I spent a lot of time before posting it here. Could you please point out the documentation link for working with vbscript and IE.

Comment: If you're interested in manipulating the DOM, refer to the MSHTML documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801967(v=vs.85).aspx). It lists the objects/events that are scriptable via VBScript/JavaScript. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772960(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

To set/change the .value - or the .text - of the option (instead of just selecting it), use

```
Helem1(2).value = "newValue"
Helem1(2).text = "newText"
```

(method to address the item stolen from Bond's answer)

Comment: Hi Ekkehard , i just tried the above code.. This did not selected the new item in the list box , also when i tried to see the source html of the page after running the code, It was exactly the same as before. Could you please explain what does the above code do ?

Comment: @user3436156 - the code does what the question you **wrote** asked for: it changes the .text/.value of the 3rd option of the select. I didn't try to answer 'How do I select an option?' because I'm not a telepath (like Bond).

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard for your help.